# Android notification sound not stopping

Tags: android, notifications

I am using the old way to show notifications. Here is my code:

```
Notification n = new Notification(R.drawable.facebookicon,"New Message",System.currentTimeMillis());


intent=new Intent(mContext,NotificationMessageShower.class);
intent.putExtra("message",message);
// use System.currentTimeMillis() to have a unique ID for the pending intent
PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(mContext, (int) System.currentTimeMillis(), intent, 0);

n.setLatestEventInfo(mContext, "New Message", message,pIntent);
n.flags = Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS | Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
Uri uri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
n.sound=uri;
n.audioStreamType = AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION;

int curNotificationId= Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MILLISECOND);
notificationManager.notify(curNotificationId, n);
```

The problem is that when notification comes, the notification sound keeps on repeating till I open the notification bar which is very annoying. How do I get rid of this so that notification sound plays just once?

I am using the old way because I want the app to run on android Api level 8 upwards. In India, many people still use old version of android, so I don't want to miss those users.

Comment: Make sure you are getting multiple response from your server

Comment: @Sridhar what it has got to do with server side?

Comment: you can print int in Log or debug